# Somehow this array is not an array?

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

The following code return some results that are baffling me...

```
if(is_array($loginUser)) {         
    $_SESSION['name'] = $loginUser['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $loginUser['id'];
    print_r($_SESSION['name']);
    print_r($loginUser);
    var_dump($loginUser[1]);
    exit();
    header("Location: ../index.php?page=home");
}
```

That returns:

> Notice: Undefined index: firstname in wwwroot/includes/userhandler.php
>   on line 124
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id in wwwroot/includes/userhandler.php on
>   line 125

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [id] => 4 [1] => Johnny [firstname] => Johnny [2] => Appleseed [lastname] => Appleseed [3] => ja@ja.com [email] => ja@ja.com [4] => johnny'shashedpassword [password] => johnny'shashedpassword ) )
```

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in wwwroot/includes/userhandler.php on
>   line 129
>
> NULL

Comment: Try with `$_SESSION['name'] =$loginUser[0]['firstname'];`

Comment: And that seems to work.

Comment: Do a `$loginUser = current($loginUser);` to fix your problem

Comment: @MohammadAlabed Because something is obvious to you, that doesn't mean it is obvious to others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` and `firstName` are stored in an array with key `0`

change

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $loginUser['firstname'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $loginUser['id'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $loginUser[0]['firstname'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $loginUser[0]['id'];
```

but I see no reason why the you have an extra dimension in your `$loginUser` array. Try to refactor the way `$loginUser` is building its array

Later in the code you are calling `var_dump($loginUser[1]);`
This returns your second error message because there is only a `$loginUser[0]`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm looking at it now to figure out why there are two arrays. I have never run into this before, and it certainly was not intentional.

Comment: no problem, we where all beginners once don't let people like Mohammad Alabed put you down. Keep programming and you will be a professional one day

Answer (score 0):

Your array is in another array. You can solve this by using the following line of code:

```
$loginUser = current($loginUser);
```

Furthermore, when using `var_dump` I always find it easy to use `<pre />` tags. This makes it easier for you to see how the array is built up.

Example:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($loginUser);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```